# C++ does begin/end/rbegin/rend execute in constant time for std::set, std::map, etc?

Tags: c++, stl

For data types such as std::set and std::map where lookup occurs in logarithmic time, is the implementation required to maintain the begin and end iterators? Does accessing begin and end imply a lookup that could occur in logarithmic time?

I have always assumed that begin and end always occur in constant time, however I can't find any confirmation of this in Josuttis. Now that I'm working on something where I need to be anal about performance, I want to make sure to cover my bases.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They happen in constant time.  I'm looking at page 466 of the ISO/IEC 14882:2003 standard:

**Table 65 - Container Requiments**

a.begin();   *(constant complexity)*

a.end();     *(constant complexity)*

**Table 66 - Reversible Container Requirements**

a.rbegin();  *(constant complexity)*

a.rend();    *(constant complexity)*

Answer (score 6):

Yes, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/, begin(), end() etc are all O(1).

Answer (score 5):

In the C++ standard, Table 65 in 23.1 (Container Requirements) lists begin() and end() as requiring constant time.  If your implementation violates this, it isn't conforming.

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the code, here you can see the iterators in the std::map in the GNU libstdc++

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

you'll see that all end rend cend ... are all implemented in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with hash_map though.  begin() is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

For std::set

begin: constant,  end: constant, 
rbegin: constant, 
rend: constant,

For std::map

they are also constant (all of them)

if you have any doubt, just check [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com)

Comment: Don't rely too much on cplusplus.com