# How does std::set guarantee constant time min/max element access?

Tags: c++, std, red-black-tree, stdset

std::set min/max element access (through begin/rbegin) is [constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83640/c-does-begin-end-rbegin-rend-execute-in-constant-time-for-stdset-stdmap). Does it achieve this by updating min/max during insertion/removal?

Comment: A set is always sorted, so the minimal and maximal values are always at the beginning and the end.

Comment: @tkausl when are beginning and end updated?

Comment: It's not hard to implement a set such that the root _is_ the "end", so then you only have to keep track of the beginning. I assume they simply have 'begin' (maybe and 'end') as additional members that they update when updating the data. Do you think this would be hard in some way?

Comment: @MooingDuck in red-black tree couldn't min and max be anywhere? For balance purposes it does not make sense to have either extreme as root.

Comment: @tkausl Whats the beginning and end of a RBTree?  OP: *Does it achieve this by updating min/max during insertion/removal?* That's really the only way to do it.

Comment: @qwr: No. In any ordered tree, the 'begin' is the leftmost leaf node, and the 'end' is 'one past the rightmost leaf node', regardless of implementation, redblack or otherwise