# Designing a constant time begin() inorder iterator function to an AVL container

Tags: c++, design-patterns, tree, iterator, containers

Good day,

If one wants to design a standard-compliant container based on a (AVL) tree, its iterator functions [have to be constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83640/c-does-begin-end-rbegin-rend-execute-in-constant-time-for-stdset-stdmap). As noted in that discussion, the look-up in a search tree tends to be logarithmic.

Suppose a traditional tree class setup where as private members we have the root node and the size. Node is also designed conventionally (having three pointers, left-right-parent), and the iterators are lazy and store the node pointers. Then to provide a `begin()` one has to go from root to far left which takes O(logn) time in worst-case scenario. So my questions are:

- What do you think is the best way to satisfy the complexity requirement for tree's `begin()`?

I was thinking of keeping another private node pointer member which will get updated after every modification but it seems to me there's a room for more optimal solution.

- For `end()`, can I just return a `nullptr`?

Comment: You could just keep a global pointer to the leftmost node in your tree and return them if `begin()` is called. You would have to keep it updated if items are inserted, but that should not be too much trouble.

Comment: For `end()`, you just want to make sure that `++iterator_to_last_element == end()`

Comment: Like Jakob said, it is a common pattern to let the tree point at the first and last node. You can also let the left child of the first node and the right child of the last node point back at the tree itself. For example std::list does this, basically forming a ring. When done right, this saves you from doing nullptr-checks, e.g. when inserting after the last element.

Comment: This ring pattern also makes a convenient end iterator. It simply points back to the tree itself.

Comment: Oh, and for end() you cannot return nullptr because ```--end()``` must give the iterator to the last element. That is used for reverse iterators.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Is there any article/blogpost discussing this circular pattern? I kind of can't wrap my head around it. @Homer512 by saying "let the tree point at the first and last node," do you mean that the `root` private node member will have its left as first node and its right as last node? won't I lose access to the middle element then? maybe I can set `root`'s parent as the middle element?  and if make last node's right child point to tree itself, how am I gonna tell `begin()` apart from `end()`?

Comment: @Mampac maybe there is some stuff on this but your best bet is looking at the STL itself. I assume that it is as you describe, the root node's "parent" is the middle node. begin() is root's left node, end() is the root node itself.

Comment: @Mampac There is some stuff in comments here. It seems slightly different but not far off from what I described. Though I haven't fully understood the structure. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__tree